# PHP: How to check if variable is a "large integer"

Tags: php

I need to check if a parameter (either string or int or float) is a "large" integer. By "large integer" I mean that it doesn't have decimal places and can exceed `PHP_INT_MAX`. It's used as msec timestamp, internally represented as float.

`ctype_digit` comes to mind but enforces string type. `is_int` as secondary check is limited to `PHP_INT_MAX` range and `is_numeric` will accept floats with decimal places which is what I don't want.

Is it safe to rely on something like this or is there a better method:

```
if (is_numeric($val) && $val == floor($val)) {
    return (double) $val;
}
else ...
```

Comment: have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#example-71

Comment: An integer variable can, by definition, not exceed PHP_MAX_INT ...

Comment: [Binary Calculator Comparison](http://php.net/bccomp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you want to check if a particular variable is integer-like?

```
function isInteger($var)
{
    if (is_int($var)) {
        // the most obvious test
        return true;
    } elseif (is_numeric($var)) {
        // cast to string first
        return ctype_digit((string)$var);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that using a floating point variable to keep large integers will lose precision and when big enough will turn into a fraction, e.g. `9.9999999999991E+36`, which will obviously fail the above tests.

If the value exceeds INT_MAX on the given environment (32-bit or 64-bit), I would recommend using [gmp](http://php.net/gmp) instead and persist the numbers in a string format.

Comment: Does only work with the enforced cast: `echo (isInteger(99999999999999)) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @andig On 32-bit, the scalar `99999999999999` is converted to a float with a fraction, e.g. `0.9999999E+XX` or something.

Comment: the point is that ctype_digit will fail if the parameter is not a string -> your code doesn't work without the cast. 99... is the largest int I've found ad-hoc that _isnt_ cast to E+XX, but you could just take PHP_INT_MAX+1 instead.... Need to downvote if not fixed??

Comment: @andig feel free to edit the cast back in, I'm outside atm; I'll check later why that's actually a requirement.

Comment: changing back because `ctype_digit($integer)` gives `false` (http://www.php.net/ctype_digit)

Comment: @andig The cast is required on 32-bit systems only, because `double` has an upper range of exactly 99999999999999 and `ctype_digit()`, for some reason, doesn't support that as can be seen [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ctype/ctype.c#L145). Thanks for testing anyway :)

Comment: @andig In fact, `ctype_digit(120)` yields false too .. because they found it amusing to let the function do two different things based on what kind of argument is passed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43259/discussion-between-andig-and-jack)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend the binary calculator as it does not care about length and max bytes. It converts your "integer" to a binary string and does all calculations that way.

BC math lib is the only reliable way to do RSA key generation/encryption in PHP, and so it can easy handle your requirement:

```
$userNumber = '1233333333333333333333333333333333333333312412412412';

if (bccomp($userNumber, PHP_INT_MAX, 0) === 1) {
    // $userNumber is greater than INT MAX
}
```

Third parameter is the number of floating digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isInteger($var)
{
    if (is_int($var)) {
        return true;
    } elseif (is_numeric($var)) {
        // will throw warning
        if (!gmp_init($var)) {
            return false;
        } elseif (gmp_cmp($var, PHP_INT_MAX) >0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return floor($var) == $var;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did
at the end of the function to check for numeric data.

```
return is_numeric($text)&&!(is_int(strpos($text,".",0)));
```

It will first check if it is numeric then check if there is no decimal in the string by checking if it found a position. If it did the returned position is an int so is_int() will catch it.

(strpos($text,".",0)==FALSE) would also work based on the strpos [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) but sometimes the function seems to send nothing at all back like

```
echo (strpos($text,".",0));
```

could be nothing and the ==FALSE is needed.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.